# Fan not running in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, overheating, fan, fancontrol

Recently i have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo G505s laptop along side win7.
It has AMD A8-5550M APU with Radeon HD Graphis and 8 Gb of ram.
But the problem is that i am unable to run ubuntu more than 40 min as my laptop become very hot.

I installed psensor and found out that temperature of my laptop was around 75 Celsius.Sometimes it become 80 also.I also found out my fan was not running.

[image]

[image]

It's not the hardware prob as fan is working while running win7.

I also installed TLP powersaver tool in ubuntu but then also no help.Still my laptop fan is not running.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your system has a bad ACPI bios that uses goofy non standard fan control mechanisms that require proprietary windows drivers and do not work in linux.  Your only hope is to install the `lm-sensors` package and see if `sensors-detect` can find hardware that `fancontrol` knows how to take over.