# Ubuntu overheating possible hw damage + defaults to gentoo kernel + initramfs-tools issue + failed to detect appropriate partition

Tags: dual-boot, kernel, asus, overheating, bug-reporting

Hardware: https://www.asus.com/us/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G750JS/specifications/

If ubuntu is installed as a dualboot with other distro it want's to use other HDD by default when first HDD has enough space for ubuntu to use and share /boot and swap. -> has to be configured manually

When ubuntu is installed the initramfs-tools fails at the installation and then prevents the system from using `apt`:

```
root@Ubuntus-G750JS:/home/kreyonubuntu# apt install fancontrol
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
fancontrol is already the newest version (1:3.4.0-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 224 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.5) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.5) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Ubuntu by default is unable to use GPU fan which results in overheating the GPU and possible hardware damage. Same issue on Live version of gentoo.. Related: https://bugs.gentoo.org/669818

If ubuntu is installed as dual-boot it defaults to 4.19.0-gentoo instead of ubuntu kernel. Should be fixed to use ubuntu kernel by default.

Those issues can be reproduced.

EDIT1: If UEFI is used with non-UEFI /boot partition the installation can't switch to non-EUFI version or to reinstall the non-UEFI on UEFI and keep the kernel images.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the initramfs-tools issue by removing it via terminal.

The issue with wrong kernel can be selected in grub and edited as permanent fix.

The overheating seems to be fixed using [Fan not running in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703580/fan-not-running-in-ubuntu-14-04)

EDIT1: The overheating is still present

EDIT2: issue with initramfs-tools was fixed by extending /boot from 128MB to 1GB. + The issue with wrong kernel.

EDIT3: The overheating issue was resolved by installing nvidia drivers 390.